# How can I retrieve data to a drop down list box in my jsp file from a function

Tags: java, sql, jsp

How can I retrieve data from SQL database (specifically from a column) to drop down list box in my JSP file? but I want to retrieve this data from a function in a .java file and the to the JSP list box so the order will be:

A function in my java file that retrieve the data from sql DB (specifically from a column) and the show it in my jps list box?

this will the function in java file

here is my code:

```
public String getc&#95;Condicion(){
    String query = "";

    String c&#95;condicion = new String();
        query = "select C&#95;Condicion&#95;Beca from Bca&#95;Condicion&#95;Beca";
        try{
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()){
                c&#95;condicion = rs.getString("C&#95;Condicion&#95;Beca");
               }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error al obtener los datos: "+e.getMessage());

        }

    return c&#95;condicion;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this? This may not be Best design wise though.

```
public String[] getcDataCondicion(){
    String query = "";

    String[] cDataCondicion= new String[100];
        query = "select C&#95;Condicion&#95;Beca from Bca&#95;Condicion&#95;Beca";
        try{
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            int i=0;
            while (rs.next()){
                cDataCondicion[i] = rs.getString("C&#95;Condicion&#95;Beca");
                 i++;
               }
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error al obtener los datos: "+e.getMessage());

        }

    return cDataCondicion;
}

<%  

  YourClass c= new YourClass();
String[] result=c.getcDataCondicion();
%>

<Select>
<%
  for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
%>
 <Option>result[i]</ Option>
<% } %>
</select>
```